# Populate the data to 2d barcode in excel using progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress 4gl. Is it possible to populate the data to 2d barcode in excel using progress 4gl? If yes then please provide some link or give a small example so that I can take a look.

```
        /* DOCX Library*/
    {slibooxml/slibxlsx.i}   
    {slib/slibos.i}
    {slib/sliberr.i}
FIND FIRST TTPACKSLIPPRINT NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
   IF AVAILABLE TTPACKSLIPPRINT THEN DO:
      RUN WriteToLog("DEBUG", "FOUND DATA IN TT TO PRINT").

      /* Copy Template to Memory */
      /* Catch and handle any thrown exceptions */  
      {slib/err_try}:

      RUN WriteToLog("DEBUG", "Loading Template File to Memory"). 
      /*etime(yes).*/
      run xlsx_copyTemplate(input "stXlsx",              /* Stream name */
                            input ipc_template_name ).   /* Template file */

      RUN WriteToLog("DEBUG", "Loading Data Area to Memory").

      /* Prepare DATA SHEET section to CUT */
      run xlsx_cut(input "stXlsx",                                    /* Stream name */
                  input "DATA" ).                                 /* Master Clipboard item name */

      RUN WriteToLog("DEBUG", "Loading Data Area to Memory completed").


        run xlsx_setClipboardValue(
                                    input "stXlsx",                         
                                    input "DATA",                           
                                    input "BOL_ID",                         
                                    input TTPACKSLIPPRINT.BOL_ID ). 


        run xlsx_setClipboardValue(input "stXlsx",                         
                                    input "DATA",                          
                                    input "GROSS_WT",                 
                                    input STRING(TTPACKSLIPPRINT.pckd_gross_weight)).

        run xlsx_setClipboardValue(input "stXlsx",                         
                                   input "DATA",                          
                                   input "NET_WT",                 
                                   input STRING(TTPACKSLIPPRINT.pckd_net_weight)). 

        run xlsx_setClipboardValue(input "stXlsx",                         
                                    input "DATA",                          
                                    input "DN_NO",                 
                                    input TTPACKSLIPPRINT.PACKSLIP_ID).

        run xlsx_setClipboardValue(input "stXlsx",                         
                                    input "DATA",                          
                                    input "DELIV_DATE",                 
                                    input DATE(TODAY)).

        run xlsx_setClipboardValue(input "stXlsx",                         
                                    input "DATA",                          
                                    input "T_LIC_PLATE",                 
                                    input "").

        run xlsx_setClipboardValue(input "stXlsx",                         
                                    input "DATA",                          
                                    input "DR_LIC_PLATE",                 
                                    input "").

        run xlsx_setClipboardValue(input "stXlsx",                         
                                    input "DATA",                          
                                    input "DRIVER_NAME",                 
                                    input TTPACKSLIPPRINT.DRIVER_NAME).


        run xlsx_setClipboardValue(input "stXlsx",                         
                                    input "DATA",                          
                                    input "SHIP_TYPE",                 
                                    input "").

        run xlsx_setClipboardValue( input "stXlsx",                         
                                    input "DATA",                           
                                    input "ADDRESS1",                         
                                    input gdmf_address.addr_address_1).

        run xlsx_setClipboardValue( input "stXlsx",                         
                                   input "DATA",                           
                                   input "ADDRESS2",                         
                                   input gdmf_address.addr_address_2).
. 
        run xlsx_setClipboardValue(  input "stXlsx",                         
                                    input "DATA",                           
                                    input "ADDRESS3",                         
                                    input gdmf_address.addr_address_3).  
       run xlsx_paste(
                        input "stXlsx",                                 
                        input "DATA",                                  
                        input ? ).                                    

       ASSIGN  opc_FileName = cFilenameprefix + STRING(TIME)
               opc_FilePath = cDNOPDir + "/" + opc_FileName + ".xlsx".

       run xlsx_save(input "stXlsx",
                     input opc_FilePath).

      {slib/err_catch cError cErrorMsg cStackTrace}:
          MESSAGE cErrorMsg
                  skip(1)
                  cStackTrace
            view-as alert-box.

           ASSIGN OERROR = cErrorMsg.

      {slib/err_end}.
  END.
```

If you see above code area I am just targeting data area in excel template and populating value to particular cells but i don't know the way how to use 2d or 1d barcode as i am noob on progress 4gl

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible.  But how you actually go about it depends an awful lot on the specifics of your environment.  To get a good quality answer you should provide some details about what version of OpenEdge you are using, what your development tool chain has available (are you using PDSOE or Notepad or ???), what version of Excel you want to target, what sort of 2D barcode, and so forth.  It would also be helpful if you describe any knowledge and experience you already have with techniques to interface OpenEdge to Excel and any code examples that you have perhaps already tried.

Comment: Hello Tom, I am using OpenEdge AppBuilder Release 11.6 for the development. I want to use PDF417 and I am targeting Excel 2007

Comment: I tried to use 2d barcode from third party and links to particular cell which will have data but I got nothing while scanning. Let me share my code